# How to solve this type of Unity Game error?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, runtime-error

I am testing my unity game in Redmi 4 (Android version 7.1.2 N2G47H, MIUI version 9.1) & I am getting following error in crash report on redmi device.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/mido/mido:7.0/NRD90M/V9.0.5.0.NCFMIEI:user/release-keys'
 Revision: '0'
 ABI: 'arm'
 pid: 21527, tid: 24307, name: Thread-79  >>> com.BitwiseVentures.TeenPattiRoyale <<<
 signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
 Abort message: 'art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:66] JNI ERROR (app bug): see above.'
    r0 00000000  r1 00005ef3  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
    r4 cd600978  r5 00000006  r6 cd600920  r7 0000010c
    r8 e6a6e800  r9 f382eacf  sl f384b07e  fp 00000000
    ip 0000000b  sp cd5ff990  lr f55df2b7  pc f55e1b38  cpsr 200f0010

> backtrace:
    #00 pc 00049b38  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 000472b3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
    #02 pc 0001d555  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 000190a1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
    #04 pc 00017104  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 00319f31  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+252)
    #06 pc 000b4ef9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+864)
    #07 pc 001bad69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable17AbortIfNoCheckJNIEv+84)
    #08 pc 0023bceb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art22IndirectReferenceTable10GetCheckedEPv+498)
    #09 pc 00334309  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+44)
    #10 pc 00315be9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8ArgArray24BuildArgArrayFromJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6mirror6ObjectEP6jvalue+160)
    #11 pc 00315a53  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+250)
    #12 pc 00272057  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI23CallStaticObjectMethodAEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+426)
    #13 pc 00a471d8  /data/app/com.BitwiseVentures.TeenPattiRoyale-2/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #14 pc 00005c4c  <anonymous:cbe0f000>
```

Please guid me if any one has resolved this type of issues. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the "Redmi" api is forgetting to clear a reference somewhere in their JNI code. Nothing you can really do about it unless you have access to the source code and know what you're doing.

Comment: This happens on every android devices.

Comment: @NeelGajjar did you solve this issue?